# Class 'DebugBarFilter' not found in cakephp3 for server

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My client project is working in localhost environment but in client server, it is giving the following fatal error:

> Error: Class 'DebugBarFilter' not found 
>   File /home/pantaid8/public_html/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/config/bootstrap.php 
>   Line: 2 
>   yes code is in 21 line but message is coming same what I mentioned.

Comment: Line _2_, really? If you look at the source, you should see that the class is first used on line _21_. So please make sure that you're really posting the correct/complete message here. And if it's actually line _21_, then start by checking the composer autoloader, dump it again, inspect `autoload_psr4.php`...

Comment: I can confirm that despite the fact that there's nothing but an opening of a block comment on line two, this "Class 'DebugBarFilter' not found" error message says that the error originates on line 2 of that file. It doesn't make sense, but I'm staring at the exact same error message as Pramod.